# Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be such that $|f(x) -f(y)| \le |x - y |^2 \ \forall \ x,\ y \in \Bbb R$. How can I show that $f$ is constant?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be such that $|f(x) -f(y)| \le |x - y |^2 \  \forall \  x,\ y \in \Bbb R$.

How can I show that $f$ is constant? To me the statement looks an awful lot like something having to do with continuity/uniform continuity, but the fact that $|x - y|$ is being raised to the power of $2$ is confusing me.. I also recognize that the problem doesn't say anything about continuity, it's just what it looks like to me. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left| \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\leq |x-y| \Rightarrow \forall x\; \exists f'(x) \mbox{ and } f'(x) = 0$$

Comment: this may be a really silly question, but what about $f(y)$? Do we care? Is it the same? Would it be, $\forall x, y \exists f'(x), f'(y)$ and $f'(x) = f'(y) = 0$?

Comment: Of course you can use the same argument to say that $f'(y)$ exists for all $y$. But this does not change anything.
You may also write $\left| \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|\leq |h| \Rightarrow \forall x\; \exists f'(x) \mbox{ and } f'(x) = 0$. This is all you need to show.

Comment: Ah! I see! Thank you, the $(x+h)$ format made it very simple to see.

Comment: You are welcome.